# ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() throw NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, winforms

in my VS 2022 Community Edition, WindowsForms Project: I have a combobox with a SelectedValueChange Event and still getting an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object not set to an instance of an object.

The code:

```
private void cmbChooseTask_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbChooseTask.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Install non clusterd instance")
    {
        Form frm = new NonClusterdInstallation();
        frm.Show();
    }

}
```

The combobox initialization is:

```
            cmbChooseTask.DataSource = new BindingSource(Dictionaries.DictTypeOfTask, null);
        cmbChooseTask.DisplayMember = "Value";
        cmbChooseTask.ValueMember = "Value";
        cmbChooseTask.SelectedItem = null;
```

and dictionary definition is:

```
        public static SortedDictionary<int, string> DictTypeOfTask = new SortedDictionary<int, string>()
    {
        { 1,"Install non clusterd instance" },
        { 2,"Install clusterd instance"},
        { 3, "Set up pre-installed cluster instance" },
        { 4, "Migration" },
        { 5, "Change Collation" },
        { 6, "Add instance to cluster" },
        { 7, "Display all" }
    };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You should be setting the `DataSource` last when binding. When you set the `DataSource`, that will cause the `SelectedValueChanged` event to be raised, but you haven't set the `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember` yet. Set those first and then the answer I provided below will work as expected. ALWAYS set the `DataSource` last.

Comment: By the way, why would you set the `ValueMember` to `"Value"`? It seems like `"Key"` would be the logical option, i.e. the control displays the text but exposes the number in code. That way, you can just do a `switch` on `SelectedValue` and test for the valid numbers. What else are the numbers for?

Comment: I would also question why you need a `Dictionary` at all. Could you not just use a `string` array and use the indexes to identify the items like you might be currently using the numeric keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why call `ToString` if it's already a `string`? Just cast it as type `string`, which will succeed for `null` too:

```cs
if ((string)cmbChooseTask.SelectedValue == "Install non clusterd instance")
```

Also, based on the text you're comparing it to, I'm guessing that you actually care about the text displayed in the control, which is exposed via the `Text` property, which is already type `string`:

```cs
if (cmbChooseTask.Text == "Install non clusterd instance")
```

Comment: unfortunately not: the error now is: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair 2 [System.Int32., System.String] to type System.String. I'm adding the combobox.Source in the question above.

Comment: @Purclot, it sounds like you're trying to bind a generic `Dictionary` to your `ComboBox` but you're doing it wrong. If the `SelectedValue` is a `KeyValuePair` then calling `ToString` on it may not throw and exception but it can never produce the actual data you're looking for. Please edit your question and show us EXACTLY how you're populating the `ComboBox` and the `Dictionary` you're binding to it.

Comment: thank you. I've placed the combobox binding code above in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution to NRE would be:

```
if (String.Equals(cmbChooseTask.SelectedValue?.ToString(), "Install non 
clusterd instance"))
```

or just

```
if (cmbChooseTask.SelectedValue?.ToString() == "Install non 
clusterd instance")
```